# am getting error when am trying to use .apply in the following code don't know why

Tags: apply

```py
def hig_beverage(x):
    if x>=10000:
        return x
    else:
        None

filt=(df["Item Type"].isin(["Beverages"]))
df.loc[filt,['Country','Item Type', 'Unit Price', 'Unit Cost', 'Total Revenue', 'Total Cost','Total Profit'],df['Total Profit'].apply(hig_beverage)]
```

this is a python code in jupyter
i want to apply my function name hig_beverage into df.loc so in can filter those number in the "Total Profit" columns which are greater than 10000, but am getting error.

Comment: Hi -- could you format your code (is this Python??), post the error message you're getting, and tell us what you expect to happen. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: And also fix typos in title. Please provide also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example